# Rstudio: I can't change a working directory in R studio

Tags: r, working-directory

I am having the issue with accessing my data file that is stored in my hard drive. The only way that I can access is to change the current working directory, but I am having the issue of changing WD. Currently the WD is in the cloud, so I was trying to change to my local directory:

```r
> setwd("/cloud")
> setwd("C:/Users/MYagi/Documents")
```

> Error in setwd("C:/Users/MYagi/Documents") :    cannot change working
> directory

Comment: Are you sure that directory exists?

Comment: `dir.exists("C:/Users/MYagi/Documents")` should be true; if not, that's the cause of your error.

Comment: Hi, After multiple trials, I finally got a conclusion that I can't change WD to a local directory, because I am using Rstudio Cloud, not a desktop version. I am not sure if this is true, but this makes sense, right? I downloaded a desktop version and Viola! I have no problem of changing WD! Being a newbie, a problem like this happen often. No one told me that Cloud base vs. desktop versioin! LOL.